# Submit text value into iframe input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to send a text value from the parent page to the iframe < input >. It's all on the same domain and folder.

Was trying this code:

```js
function addNick(nick) {
    var txt = parent.document.getElementById('input').value;
    parent.document.getElementById('mess').value = 'to[' + nick + '] ' + txt;
    parent.document.getElementById('mess').focus();
}
```

```
<iframe src="input.php" name="input" id="input" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

Text is triggered in **mess.php** to be submitted with link to the above iframe input.

```
 <a href="javascript:addnick('Name')">name</a>
```

which is printed in index.php with js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 setInterval(function(){//setInterval() method execute on every interval until called clearInterval()
  $('#load_posts').load("mess.php").fadeIn("slow");
  //load() method fetch data from mess.php page
 }, 1000);
 
});
```

So basically the addNick code won't work.

Any help will be much appreciated.

***FINAL SOLUTION***

```js
function addNick(nick) {
     var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
//the element you want to target:
        var mess = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("mess").value += `${nick}, `;
}
```

Comment: What error (if any) are you getting?

Comment: @Luke I don't get any errors. It's just when I try to trigger it to be sent to iframe with <a href="javascript:addnick('Name')">, nothing happens. Could it be an issue because I load mess.php on index page with setInterval js function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first get the iframe element by id, then target the element within the iframe..
so if input.php has an `<h1></h1>` tag this will set the innerHTML to what the parameter nick holds..

```
        function addNick(nick) {
        
        var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
//the element you want to target:
        var mess = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0]; 
    mess.innerHTML = `to ${nick}`
    }
```

On how to access dom of iframe, check out this example:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_element_iframe

Comment: When put into index page or input.php, nothing happens..

Comment: Your javascript loocks a bit wierd  parent.document where is its eather the parent.getElement... or dockument.getElement...

Comment: I'm not strong in js, to be honest. What I was trying to get is that from index.php where the iframe is located, text from link  <a href="javascript:addnick('Name')"> would be sent to input iframe, but couldn't reach the desired result

Comment: Yes! This one with H1 worked perfectly! It changed H1 to the text in link. Now I need it to put this exactly text into input as value :D Like maybe change the part of code to... getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value ?

Comment: what do you mean by "this exactly text into input as value"?

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using this code, which resolved everything for me! function addNick(nick) {
     var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
//the element you want to target:
        var mess = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("mess").value = `${nick}, `;
}